# Installing full Debian 9 to USB

Tags: linux, usb, debian, installation

I currently have Windows 10 and I am trying to install Debian 9 on USB, not the live version. I already tried but failed. I used two USBs, one for the install image and booted from it and other USB on which I wanted to install Debian 9, so I followed the graphical install guide, there was an error when trying to setup my network. It said it is lacking additional firmware. I ignored it and continued to install and when it was over I tried to boot from that USB and all I got was black screen with blinking cursor.

Now I'm going to try to download non-free version for additional firmware, but I'm interested to know if I'm doing this correctly and should I install the GRUB boot loader onto the USB or the computer.

Comment: **It depends**. Is it BIOS or UEFI? Do you want it to boot from other computers or use it only in the same computer?

Comment: i want to boot it from any computer, and im not sure is it BIOS or UEFI

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the windows program "rufus" (for booting/installing software)
2. Select the drive that you want to act as the installer disc (USB)
3. Select the file (.iso or other) with the data to install
4. Continue after formatting the drive, it will ask to write in ISO image mode or DD image mode (Choose DD)

After the firmware is installed on the external drive, reboot the computer and halt the startup of your computer.  This is usually done by using the escape, F9, or F11 keys.

5. Choose boot from EFI
6. Choose your USB
7. Choose the grub(x82/64)
8. Linux will boot. From here, run it live or install on a DIFFERENT external drive.

Answer (score 0):

While a live install isn't what you want, the [Debian live ISO](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/) will allow you to install Debian (non-live) to your USB drive, as well as providing live boot functionality. Just select the graphical installer on the menu that appears when you boot the CD. It does not not need network access, as all firmware needed is on the CD itself. (At least with the Debian Stretch ISO I used. They might have changed it with 9.5, although that is unlikely)

EDIT: As for GRUB, when the installer asks you about it, pick your USB drive.